# Why "invoke-command" is not takeing anything? -- Powershell

Tags: powershell

when I run this scrip, there is a error: "'BatchManager.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command"

```
 Param ([string] $par1)
>>
>> $user = "xxx\app-xxxxxx"
>> $secpasswd = (Get-Content "cred.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString)
>> $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($user, $secpasswd)
>> $s = New-PSSession -computerName CESxxxxxxxx -credential $cred
>> Write-Output "Upload date on Powershell : " $par1
>>
>> Try {
>> $result = Invoke-Command -Session $s -Scriptblock { & cmd.exe /c "G:\Automate\WInversion_CargaD\WInversion_CargaD.bat" $par1 $args[0] }  -ArgumentList $par1 -ErrorAction Stop
>> }
>> Catch {
>>                 Write-Host "Error invocar comando powershell"
>>                 $result = $error[0]
>>                 Write-Host $result
>> }
>> Remove-PSSession $s
```

I don't find the fail but I am pretty sure that the problem is in the "Invoke-Command" or at least that is what I think.

Comment: The error measn BatchManager.exe is not found no the remote computer. Is it in path? Does the batch file use full path?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I think both questions are true but I am not 100*100 sure about that because is not my system and i don ´t have access to the remote computer. This is a client who try to automatice a process with this scrip and it doesn´t work and they say that is ours problem. So now I am checking this script and why is failing.

Comment: @vonPryz you had reason the problem is the path of the .bat. Thank you a lot.